# Webpack dynamic request

Tags: webpack, commonjs

It's not working

```
let serviceName = "AuthService";
let servicePath = `app/services/${serviceName}`; 
let service     = require(servicePath);
```

It's working

```
let service = require("app/services/AuthService");
```

How can I use webpack dynamic modules?

Error:

```
Cannot find module 'app/services/AuthService'.
```

I written log message at the end of file and it was shown before module error.

As I found in doc just need use a simple require. (https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html#dynamic-requires)

I don't think that I need create my own context for this work.

Comment: have you tried to import?

Comment: Daenarys, if you talking about "imports?" then yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

There are two options to make this:

1) You need to provide specific expressions:

```
let serviceName = "AuthService";
let service  = require('./app/services/' + serviceName);
```

webpack parses the require statement and extracts some information(directory, regular expression) for building context.

2) You can create your own context with the require.context function:

```
let serviceName = "AuthService";
let context = require.context('./app/services', false);
let service = context('./' + serviceName);
```

[image]

See more https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html

Comment: I tried first option, but it doesn't work. From debugging i understood that this module doesn't exist in webpack module list and I don't know why

Comment: Maybe you need to check your paths

Comment: let serviceName = propertyKey.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + propertyKey.slice(1);
    let servicePath = `./app/services/${serviceName}`;
    let service     = require(servicePath);


Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './app/services/AuthService'.

Then it's magic...

Comment: Maybe it's important but i use this code in annotations

Comment: require(servicePath) it will not work. I've write the exact structure of calling require method. require('./app/services/' + serviceName) - only this way, no temp variable like servicePath

Comment: in my case I don't need put ./