# Using dynamic requires in webpack with plugins

Tags: webpack

I have come across this questions [Webpack dynamic request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36398962/webpack-dynamic-request)

which explains the require.context method.

The documentation does not make clear how to use a plugin with `require.context`

this works `require('inject!myModule.js')`
this does not `const injectPath = 'inject!myModule.js'; require(injectPath);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works like this:

```
const req = require.context('plugin!./path/to/src/', true);
req('./'+modulePath)
```